# Should review of merge request include review of code style?

Tags: teamleader

On the project (scrum with java, kotlin) we don't have any code style convention - so every team leader ask write code in for-a-bit other manner.
I work in the company on several projects -
as a result, every my merge request on different team's project has a lot of issues about code style.
What i can do in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

You should escalate problem (cause it sounds real and objectively exists) - the decision can be creating such code convention.
Not for all company, maybe, but for your department or several teams with identical tech stack.